# The irreducibility of determinant

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the  determinant of the matrix $A = [x_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ as a polynomial in the ring $\Bbb{R}[x_{11},\dots,x_{nn}]$. How can I show that it is irreducible ?